# How to avoid The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-volley

I have two class. One is my `SettingsActivity` and a class where my `volley` does the work. In my web service it has a lot of data where it needed to be converted to an `ArrayList` and will be saved to my `Database`; I have a two web service to be call after the first one is done before the second one will start it is delayed 1 second. After those things it in my `Log` it always displays the following

```
 I/Choreographer: Skipped 226 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
 V/RenderScript: 0x5595d9d0e0 Launching thread(s), CPUs 8
 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 20.500ms
 W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/data/com.app.myapp/databases/myDB.sqlite' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
 I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 38249(2025KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(968KB) LOS objects, 40% free, 16MB/26MB, paused 569us total 130.628ms
 I/Choreographer: Skipped 1528 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

I already check if my database is close after using and all of it is closed. But I'm still having the `database is leaked` message and `Skipped xxx frames`. I already tried to create a new thread where I call my class in my `SettingsActivity` when calling the `class` for my `Volley` like

```
   btnSync.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {

  Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    Parameter.parameterOneVolley(SettingsActivity.this, getApplicationContext());
                }
            });
    }
    });
```

After trying this I encounter `Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

Then also tried using this

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Parameter.parameterOneVolley(SettingsActivity.this, getApplicationContext());
                }
            });
```

But this I'm having an the message `Skipped frames`. How to solve it? Thank you so much in advance for the help.

In my `Paramater` class I'm also calling `ProgressDialog`.

Here's my code for `Paramter.parameterOneVolley`

```
public static void parameterOneVolley(final Activity activity, final Context context) {

    final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    pd.setMessage("Fetching data....");
    pd.show();

    initializeDatabase(context);
    sqLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(activity);

    regionList = new ArrayList<Region>();
    divisionList = new ArrayList<Division>();


    final Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener = new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            try {

                JSONArray regionArr = response.getJSONArray("Region");
                JSONArray divisionArr = response.getJSONArray("Division");

                sqLiteAdapter.openToRead();



                    for(int i = 0; i < regionArr.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject regionObj = (JSONObject) regionArr.get(i);
                        Region region = new Region(regionObj.getInt("RegionId"),regionObj.getString("Region"));

                        regionList.add(region);


                    if(regionList.size()!=0) {
                        sqLiteAdapter.insertOrReplaceRegion(regionList);
                    }
                }


                    for(int i = 0; i < divisionArr.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject divisionObj = (JSONObject) divisionArr.get(i);
                        Division division = new Division(divisionObj.getInt("RegionId"),divisionObj.getInt("DivisionId"),divisionObj.getString("Division"));

                        divisionList.add(division);


                    if(divisionList.size()!=0) { sqLiteAdapter.insertOrReplaceDivision(divisionList);
                    }
                }

                sqLiteAdapter.close();

                if(pd != null && pd.isShowing()) {
                    pd.dismiss();
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                sqLiteAdapter.close();

                if(pd != null && pd.isShowing()) {
                    pd.dismiss();
                }

                Toast.makeText(context,
                        e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


            Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully synced.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   //call next web service
                    final Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            parameterTwoVolley(activity, context);
                    }
                    }, 1000);

        }
    };

    final Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            if(pd != null && pd.isShowing()) {
                    pd.dismiss();
                }

            if (error.networkResponse != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error Response code: " + error.networkResponse.statusCode);
                Toast.makeText(context, error.networkResponse.statusCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error Response code: Timeout/NoConnection");
                Toast.makeText(context, "Timeout/NoConnection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error Response code: AuthFailureError");
                Toast.makeText(context, "AuthFailureError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error Response code: ServerError");
                Toast.makeText(context, "ServerError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error Response code: NetworkError");
                Toast.makeText(context, "NetworkError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error Response code: ParseError");
                Toast.makeText(context, "ParseError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            if(pd != null && pd.isShowing()) {
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

---

I tried adding

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    pd = new ProgressDialog(activity);
            pd.setMessage("Fetching data....");
            pd.show();
        }
                }
            });

activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(pd != null && pd.isShowing()) {
                        pd.dismiss();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully synced.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

every time I'm using `Progress Dialog and Toast` but I still encountering `Skipped frames`

Also tried using `ProgressBar` instead and show and hide it but still encountering `skipped frames`

Comment: Depend on what you are doing `Parameter.parameterOneVolley` method. wrap only UI related parts in `runOnUiThread`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android, only the Main thread (also called the UI thread) can update views. This is because in Android the UI toolkit s not thread safe.

When you try to update the UI from a worker thread Android throws this exception. If you want to update the UI from another Thread use Handler.

```
final Handler handler=new Handler();
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       //your code
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 Parameter.parameterOneVolley(SettingsActivity.this, getApplicationContext());
            }
        });
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: In order to make this a helpful answer, you want to add some more explanations ...

Comment: where should I put it? on my SettingsActivity ?

Comment: running some methods in UI thread can also reduce the skipping of frames in main thread.

Comment: i still keeps on having skipped frames :( I also tried it to put only when I'm calling Progress Dialog and Toast but I still encounter it

Comment: i tried to remove the progress dialog and just add the code above it doesn't show skipped frames anymore but I need to show the progress dialog is there a way to do it?